# Excel Data connection wont import MS Access columns containing no data

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010

I have a large number of tables that were created by physically cutting and pasting data from MS Access queries.
I created Excel data links, to replace the cutting and pasting,
but then realized that null columns are not being imported.
Cutting and pasting, and entire Access table works, but running the same query via a data link, drops all the null columns.
Is there a way to force Excel read the null columns?

This is the connection string that Excel uses:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="";User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\Desktop\Monthly Reports\CPI-MSTR-MONTHLY.mdb;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="";Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False
```

Comment: There are several ways to import data into Excel.  Please show the method that you're using.

Comment: standard Data import using Access. I'll add the connection string to the original question: it's too long to display here

Comment: "Standard"... via the ribbon? VBA? otherwise?  Is it from an old `.MDB`? (That's a key piece of information as well.)  Can this file not be upgraded. (I'm not saying that will or wont' solve *this* issue, but it does makes things easier all-around if when everything's on the same playing field and conversion isn't necessary.)

Comment: it is a "standard", via the ribbon, data link. The mdb gets updated daily, but been around for decades, ( this is a bank, and these guys are are very, very slow, making changes). The file cannot be upgraded, so I'm stuck with what I have.